# How to fix net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 java web app?

Tags: java, security, request-headers, response-headers

I am working on a java web app and I am setting the **jsessionid** attributes: HttpOnly, Secure and SameSite in the doFilter() method of InitSession class. I have this set as such:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    Cookie jsessionCookie = RequestHelper.getCookie(request, SESSION_COOKIE_NAME);
                SecurityWrapperResponse
                        securityWrapperResponse = new SecurityWrapperResponse(response, "sanitize");
                String contextPath = request.getServletContext() != null && StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getServletContext().getContextPath()) ? request.getServletContext().getContextPath() : ROOT_CONTEXT;
                ESAPI.httpUtilities().setHeader("Set-Cookie", jsessionCookie.getName() + "=" + jsessionCookie.getValue() + SESSION_PATH_ATTRIBUTE + contextPath + SAME_SITE_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES);
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

When navigating to the 3rd page in the app I get the error:
**net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200**
This only started happening after I setHeader with the code above. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by updating an old library that needed this update: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.directwebremoting/dwr/3.0.2-RELEASE